# ng-model is not getting date value from date-picker

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, asp.net-mvc-4, angularjs

**I am using jqueryUI date-picker for inputting the ReceivedByDate. But my ng-model for retrieving date value is always passing null value. I am working with asp.net mvc 4 with angularJs. Here is my code:**

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.ReceivedByDate, new { autocomplete = "off", ng_model = "requisition.ReceivedByDate" })

<p>{{requisition.ReceivedByDate}}</p>
```

**My script for datepicek is like this:**

```
$(function () {
    $("#ReceivedByDate").datepicker({
        changeMonth: true,
        changeYear: true
    });
    $("#ReceivedByDate").datepicker("option", "dateFormat", "yy-mm-dd");
});
```

**Although when I select a date but the value inside the *"< p> < /p>"* remains null. It seems always holding null. What wrong am I doing?**

Comment: You need something like this https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-date. Basically one needs to create a directive. I highly recommend you try to read as much AngularJS documentation as possible. Angular is not a replacement for jquery hence you need to unlearn some stuff and learn new ways of doing stuff. See here too http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14994391/how-do-i-think-in-angularjs-if-i-have-a-jquery-background?rq=1

Comment: Thanks for your suggesstion Chandermani.

I've got a way to use JqeuryUI datepicker from here:
http://jsfiddle.net/simpulton/WzEvs/

This is the extended version:
http://www.abequar.net/jquery-ui-datepicker-with-angularjs/

Comment: `ng_model` should be `ng-model` I guess?

Comment: No Satpal, for Razorview the attributes that contains dash(-) is need to pass underscore(_) in place of dash(-). If you use dash(-) you will get error.